# AngularJS - How to escape html in ng-model in a textarea field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angular1.6

I have a textarea field like this :

```
<textarea id="user_about" maxlength="500" name="about" 
ng-model="foo.bar"></textarea>
```

Now, using this a user an update his info - problem is i need to escape html so stuff like

```
$amp;
```

doesnt show, but instead i get a normal &.

I tried using ng-bind-html, however i need two way data binding,

What would be the best way to do this ?

Comment: Is user entering html or is it html that was previously retrieved from model and needs to be escaped before passing to view?

Comment: its past information that user already entered - its like a n about me section. so it works fine when outputing it as text but when user wants to.edit it is where i run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

The browser does the best job converting html entities to text

Before you pass data to view can convert to text by doing:

```
$scope.foo.bar = angular.element('<div>').html($scope.foo.bar).text()
```